# How to take excel database and put data into word template automatically?

Tags: excel, ms-word

I am trying to make a membership list in MSExcel 2013 that will automatically, or upon "rendering" the document, transfer each row onto a new page in Word with a template -- each column's value in the designated position on the template.

The purpose of this membership list is to send out payment amounts to each member. I'd prefer to be able to do this without using external coding (unless it is easy to do with Python).

Comment: Sounds like Mail Merge

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning to read excel files in Java right now.

There is a library that I imported. You can download the library at the link below. It is a zip file. Import the jxl.jar into your library. Add it to the project directory. This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65igZdK9Vd4 did me good on getting it set up.

The zip file has a tutorials.html which I am reading through right now. There is a Workbook, Sheet, and Cell class that I am working with. I am going through the tutorial file at this moment. I hope this helps you get started.

http://poi.apache.org/download.html

Comment: I can access excel data in Python using some libraries similar to that one, but the thing is that putting the into a word template is quite cumbersome, and editing PDF files is a mess.